# Prevent direct access to any PHP files on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have built a site with **codeigniter 3**.

I want to prevent run all **php** files directly. imagine that I have a file named test.php in my root.

When the user goes to a **site.com/test.php** , it is not possible to access it. Not for a specific file but for all **PHP files**.

I want to access the site only by calling the controls and their methods like : **site.com/user/login**

Comment: The proper way to do this is not with .htaccess, but by putting the PHP files _outside the document root_. The only PHP file that should exist in the document root is your front controller index.php.

Comment: @AlexHowansky i know i must put all PHP files outside the document root but imagine a hacker can upload `test.php` on root and he will be able to execute file from url.

Comment: Treat the disease, not the symptom. If a hacker can upload files to your document root then they can change the file(s) that you allow (i.e., index.php) and this question becomes irrelevant. It's useless to band-aid your own security on top of an insecure host. Fix your server first. I'd start by dropping your shared hosting, there's no reason for that in 2023. Use a private VPS, cloud host, or container host.

Comment: I agree with both points, but also wanted to mention that there is a more practical reason why you want to avoid direct access to php files. You might want to use features or libraries not in CI. Files of such libraries typically will not come with a direct-access check. Manually changing those files would be annoying and a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @AlexHowansky but maybe a hacker has the ability to create a file in the root only by directly access the PHP files! and inject the PHP code into that file with the command, and this is not about uploading the file at all. it's better to prevent run php files directly!

Comment: "Files of such libraries" should be installed outside the document root, and thus wouldn't ever _need_ a direct access check...

Comment: @AlexHowansky that was part of my point - _everything_ that isn't public should be outside the document root, as you said. There is a reason why the typical document root is /var/www/**html**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it by adding this codes in **.htaccess** file :

```
RewriteEngine on

# Block direct access to PHP files except index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Now every request for .php file from url redirects to 404 page. :)

Comment: Except it won't work for .phtml files. Or .inc files. Or demo .htm(l) files from libraries. Etc.

Comment: @Christian in codeigniter we only need `index.php` from root. everything else is read by this door .

Comment: I know how CI works. I meant that if you have those other files in your project, they will still be directly accessible (with that config in your answer). So you would end up having to block a whole list of file extensions.

Comment: @Christian i got it . tanx i will update answer

Answer (score 1):

> I want to prevent [to] run all php files directly. [... I]magine that I have a file named test.php in my root.

Yes and no. You want to execute PHP files directly, because that's the case for `index.php` of the application you're using. It's still a PHP application.

However you don't want to execute unintended PHP files in the root. Here is how you can prevent that:

- Do not add files to the root you don't want to have there

And furthermore:

- Make the root directory read only
- Make all directory entries read only (recursively)

In short: Don't fight the framework you're using but understand how you deploy an application with it properly and discuss the requirements with the hoster/sysadmin of the system you've in mind to use.

First consider your requirements, then solve them with configuration. Your requirement is to run the application safely. Production defaults of it should be safe and if not, the hosting you're using is not appropriate for that application (or less likely, the application itself is not suitable for hosting — which I doubt as this is what it has been written for).

Otherwise you have the problem that you're using code to solve a problem that lies outside of the code and that normally does not work well as the abstraction is more than just leaking. The application server (Apache2 here) can't properly serve your application when you try to be more clever than it is. You also can't trick the system both the application and the server are running on. Always apply control one level higher, as it helps you to be effective and it is much easier to grasp. That means you have less implications with a deployment, which makes it more standard and this will give you peace of mind at the end of the day.

So don't get impressed by your fears, but instead talk and discuss the issues you see being facing with those who can make a difference, like your server administrator.

And if you love to tinker (like you put your explorative hacking hut on), get a virtual machien (VM), provision it and have a lab where you can really bend all the things until it breaks and beyond. Which I'd also recommend, as this is astonishingly easy these days, just rediscovered the pleasure of using Vagrant with Ansible provision. It are often the simple things that make a difference.

Note that my suggestion to have things read only also applies to the `.htaccess` file. Consult the manual of the server software that you're using and try to understand [what the configuration is in general and `.htaccess` mechanics in specific](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html) (it's always good to already be informed what a sysadmins perspective could be) and apart from that, understand that having this file read-only also makes mandatory that your applications code can not modify it after deployment (some applications like WordPress for example expect that, so double check how much technical debt — if not even bankruptcy — the application has, which is often much more of a risk you're facing).

Shared hosting may offer `.htaccess`, then this can be applicable (it's documented in the manual as well). Nevertheless as the server is making use of modules, you should write any directives that aren't from the server core but from modules gated with conditionals, so that they are only applied when the module is loaded (as otherwise you will not host even files but show a 500 internal server error message).

Just decide what you prefer, this is configuration, so it is important. First find out what is right for you, *then* you configure the server software. Then you test the configuration. If the topic is new and as you're already sensing, get a sparring partner, ideally the system administrator of that system.

If you make use of rewrite conditions and rules, first decide on your requirements, then pick the appropriate directives, parameters and flags. The rewrite module is powerful and it is therefore easy to do unintended things with it when not properly understood.

As I see you're in favor of a specific way of doing things (per your own answer), it invites me to place a reminder that if you want a 404 response, you can just have it (read the manual first, not understanding it with a single read is not an argument to not read it at all). There is no need to change the path to an unintended place as you're obviously not aware what you're doing (no offence, we all need to learn, and with mod rewrite there lay years in front of us where we — as mere mortals — always do find new behavior — otherwise file your own changes upstream, but then you do not only need to read the manual, but also the code. That's an option for the software you're using, so consider this as well if you'd like to do its configuration).

Answer (score 0):

The sure-fire way - which is also the approach most modern php frameworks use - is to actually have a document root that does not contain php files you don't want exposed.

This can also be done in codeigniter with a little trick:

1. First make a `public/` directory in your project. This will be the document root, everything in there will be public.
2. Create a simple `index.php` file there with just "hello world" for testing
3. Change your server's config to have that directory as the document root. For example, if the typical/current document root is `/var/www/html`, in your case, it should now be `/var/www/html/public`.
4. Ensure it works: when you visit the site, the "hello world" should show up. You also should not be able to access any other php files.
5. (optional) At this point you can also implement url rewriting (similar to what Dev Kraken mentioned before). Then when you access non-existing urls, you should also/always get "hello world".
6. Finally, replace the content of the index.php that we created to so:

```php
<?php

// this makes codeigniter believe that it is running from the project root, not public directory
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

// ..and this loads codeigniter
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../index.php');
```

Comment: What do you mean by modern frameworks? Laravel?

Comment: That's your take-away from the entire answer? Which modern frameworks?

But I'll bite: both laravel and symfony do it like this.

Comment: To be clear: *like this => with a public directory - the chdir hack is just for CI.